# For which values of $b,c$ is the matrix invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

$A =\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & b \\
-1 & 0 & c \\
-b & -c & 0 \end{array}\right)$

I tried to come up with the RREF($A$), but in the final step I have the matrix:

$A =\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & -c \\
0 & 1 & b \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$

Which I then conclude that no values of $b,c$ can make the matrix invertible (since the RREF($A$) doesn't have a pivot in the final row- a unique solution does not exist). Is there a way that I can verify this result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A$ is invertible iff $\det(A) \neq 0$.

$\det(A) = 0(0 + c^2 ) - 1(0 + bc)+b(c-0) = 0 - bc + bc = 0$.

Therefore, $\det(A)$ doesn't depend on values of $b, c$. Therefore, $A$ is not invertible for **any** values of $b,c$.

Comment: Oops, yes. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Find the determinant and find where it is zero.